# Determining dates of last use for tables/views in an Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

At work, my team accesses and works in a number of different databases using our team login. We have a ton of tables and views in each respective schema and I would guess that only ~10% are used regularly. As such, I would like to clean up these schemas to keep only those tables and views which are actually used and delete all the other ones (or at least archive them).

Is there any way for me to see the last time that a view was run, or the last time that a table was queried? My thinking is that if I can see that a view/table hasn't been used in x amount of time, then I'd feel more comfortable dropping it. My fear is that without such a process, I might drop tables/views that are used in Tableau dashboards and for other purposes.

Comment: I think there is only 1 way to check it is through created_date/updated_date column,that too if you are constantly adding up data in your tables. You cannot check in oracle at what time a table was last queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [Link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2613235100346955813)

DBA_HIST tables can show you data depending till what date data is stored but not beyond that and it wont be conclusive.